# Retrieving multiple values with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a file which I am using to parse articles in the reference section of wikipedia. I currently have it set up in such a way that it returns the URLs of any item in the reference section.

I'm trying to get it to export a single line containing both the link (which it does currently) and the text of the link in either a single line:

```
https://this.is.the.url "And this is the article header"
```

or over consecutive lines:

```
https://this.is.the.url
"And this is the article header"
```

### Link Sample

```
 <a 
   rel="nofollow" 
   class="external text" 
   href="https://www.mmajunkie.usatoday.com/2020/08/gerald-meerschaert-tests-positive-covid-19-ed-herman-fight-off-ufc-on-espn-plus-31/amp">
   "Gerald Meerschaert tests positive for COVID-19; Ed Herman fight off UFC on ESPN+ 31"
 </a>
```

### Scraper

```
import requests
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = requests.Session()
selectWikiPage = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UFC_Fight_Night:_Waterson_vs._Hill"


if "wikipedia" in selectWikiPage:
    html = session.post(selectWikiPage)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")
    references = bsObj.find('ol', {'class': 'references'})
    href = BeautifulSoup(str(references), "html.parser")
    links = [a["href"] for a in href.find_all("a", class_="external text", href=True)]
    title = [a["href"] for a in href.find_all("a", class_="external text", href=True)]
    for link in links:
        print(link)

else:
    print("Error: Please enter a valid Wikipedia URL")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it:

```
import requests
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = requests.Session()
selectWikiPage = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UFC_Fight_Night:_Waterson_vs._Hill"

if "wikipedia" in selectWikiPage:
    html = session.post(selectWikiPage)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")
    references = bsObj.find('ol', {'class': 'references'})
    href = BeautifulSoup(str(references), "html.parser")

    for a in href.find_all("a", class_="external text", href=True):
        listitem = [a["href"],a.getText()]

        print(listitem)

else:
    print("Error: Please enter a valid Wikipedia URL")
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of only getting the `href` attribute of the anchor tag you can also get the text of the link.

This can be done simply by

```
links = [(a["href"], a.text)
         for a in href.find_all("a", class_="external text", href=True)]
for link, title in links:
    print(link, title)
```

Now each `links` element will be a `tuple` with the link and the title.
You can now display it however you want.

Also the `a.text` can be written in like `a.getText()` or `a.get_text()` so choose what suits your code style.